File/folder status icon is not changing
I'm implementing a user-mode file system desktop app, using IT HIT library.
With the latest library version I started to face a problem with changing status icon.
In a conflict scenario (file/folder created both in local machine and in virtual drive) file/folder is initially marked in-sync (sync icon in status column in File Explorer).
After processing I try to change the icon. I set error status for the file or folder, then update UI, but icon in File Explorer doesn't change to Error icon (red circle with white cross).
I've spent several days trying to understand why this happens. There is minimal information on IT HIT library in the internet.
If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, please help me out.
Thanks.

If it's a commercial library issue you should contact the vendor.
